# I have jagged lines when trying to fit a linear model

Tags: r, hierarchy

When using the mammal dataset in R i am trying to fit a hierarchal model using the danger variable. However using the following code bellow i get a jagged line rather that a linear one. it seems that its not generalising very well, its fitting out data too well and i need a linear relationship here. Does anyone know how to solve this, code is bellow;

- fyi body and gestation have been log transformed already here, and wont work without this

  ```
   #random slope model
   hie3 = lmer(dream ~ body + gestation + (1|danger), data = mammal)
   summary(hie3)

   mammal$hie3_predictions = predict(hie3)
   hie_plot3 = ggplot(aes(x = body + gestation, y = hie3_predictions,
                  color = danger), data = mammal) +
           geom_line(size=1) +
          geom_point(aes(y = dream)) 
   hie_plot3
  ```

Data set used can be in R as standard

Comment: What you are plotting doesn't make much sense. Your x axis is the sum of two logged variables, which doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Also, `mammal` isn't an included data set in R. It looks like a version of the mammal sleep data set, but there are lots of packages that use slightly different versions of this. Which one are you using?

Comment: Should just be the default one as mammals. Also I cant see an issue with plotting 2 logged variables when trying to predict dream?

Comment: what would be the units on the x axis? What is the physical meaning of the log of body weight plus the log of gestation period? How would a reader interpret that? The regression formula you are using is modelling the effect of `dream` on two fixed effect variables, so it is finding the best fitting plane through a three-dimensional set of points, not the best fitting _line_ of dreams against the sum of the two dependent variables. Don't be confused by the `+` sign in the regression formula. It's not a literal addition, but in the ggplot call you are treating it as though it is.

Comment: And there is definitely no built in `mammals` dataset in base R. It must be from one of the packages you have installed. Can you please include all the `library` calls you have in your current session?